# Convergence of this Sum of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

$(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ sequence of independent random variables such that
$$
P(X_n=x) = \begin{cases} 0.5 \text{, x=-1} \\ 0.5 \text{, x=1}\\ 0 \text{, otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
$N \in Po(\lambda)$ independent of $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$.

$Y = X_1 + X_2 + ...+X_N$.

I want to show that $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution as $\lambda \to \infty$, how can this be done? I suspect that I ought to use the properties of the probability generating function or the characteristic function to prove the convergence.

Comment: what do you mean by $P_0$ ?

Comment: @GCab Poisson distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Using the independence of $N$ and $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ show that $$\mathbb{E}e^{i \xi Y} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( i \xi (X_1+\ldots+X_n) \right) \mathbb{P}(N=n) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left( \mathbb{E}e^{i \xi X_1} \right)^n \mathbb{P}(N=n).$$
2. Show that $$\mathbb{E}e^{i \xi X_1} = \cos \xi.$$
3. Conclude from the first two steps that $$\mathbb{E}e^{i \xi Y} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(\lambda \cos \xi)^n}{n!}  = e^{-\lambda(1-\cos \xi)}.$$
4. Use $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$ to show that $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \mathbb{E}e^{i \xi Y/\sqrt{\lambda}} = \exp \left( - \frac{\xi^2}{2} \right)$$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.